# Why is T1-separability not preserved by continuous maps?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

From Willard's "General Topology" (section 13.3), [edit: I thought that] it seems that the T1 separation axiom is preserved by the quotient topology, meaning that it is preserved by continuous maps.

(Edit: Willard is actually claiming exactly the opposite, and this is clarified in exercise 13B that I failed to look at before coming here...)

How is it so? The author is leaving it as an exercise (and I am failing).

I have tried to prove it by showing that, if $X$ is $T_1$, $\forall f: X \rightarrow Y$ a continuous map, $\forall y \in Y$ we would have $f^{-1}(y)$ closed in $X$.

But, while it would have been easy if $f^{-1}(y)$ was finite, this seems tough in the general case...

Could anybody give me a hint to the general proof?

(Edit: of course I should have looked at the book more carefully... Now, thank you anyway for the great help! I could have overlooked that several more days without this precious feedback...)

Comment: Take a look at this https://books.google.gr/books?id=UQiZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=quotient+maps+preserve+t1&source=bl&ots=A3u-HsWdK5&sig=ACfU3U1iczCbzuyXDva6lyBWmLTz3FWrOQ&hl=el&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7gOi23arlAhUTqXEKHQPGDmUQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=quotient%20maps%20preserve%20t1&f=false

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! So it was difficult to prove because wrong...

Comment: You should have looked at the exercise first, nowhere does Willard say what you're claiming he does.

Comment: You're right... I should update my question to reflect the fact that it was not Willard's claim in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise he refers to is 13.B and that says: show that the quotient space of a $T_1$ space need not be $T_0$ but that the *closed* image of a $T_1$ space is $T_1$.

The former can be shown by example (decompose $\Bbb R$ into two classes $\Bbb Q$ and the irrationals and we get a two point indiscrete quotient space) while the latter is a trivial consequence of $\{y\}= f[\{x\}]$ for some preimage point $x$ of $y$, where we use $Y$ (or $X$) is $T_1$ iff all singletons are closed.

Comment: Thank you a lot! That solves my problem :) And the book linked by Amontillado in the comments even provides  an example showing that the quotient of a $T_1$ space does not need to be $T_1$.

Comment: @almaus. It is. Let $q$ be the function that sends rationals to $0$ and irrationals to $1$. If we give $\{0,1\}$ the quotient topology w.r.t. $q$ we see that $q$ is continuous under that topology on $\{0,1\}$. And the quotient topology is indiscrete so not $T_0$.

Comment: Yep, sorry I deleted my comment as I was getting aware I was wrong. I was saying that the example map is not continuous, but of course it is because we use the very quotient topology induced by the map! You are right.